# understand how opsworks and custom cookbooks work together

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks, cookbook

I have my stack on opsworks and app is deploying fine (cake php).

Now I have to configure some things like chmod, php versions, etc etc... I'm reading about this but don't know exactly whats the best way to do this.

Question 1 - Should I do this with custom deploy JSON or via custom cookbooks?

Question 2 - Whats the correctly way to work with custom cookbooks? Fork original AWS repositories, update recipes and then use it in my stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depends on what you would like to achieve, you may implement many things, such as:

1. a [recipe](https://docs.chef.io/recipes.html), which is invoked only once during a `chef-client` run.
2. a [lightweight resource provider](https://docs.chef.io/lwrp.html), which supports `notifies` and can be invoked zero or more times.
3. a [definition](http://docs.chef.io/definitions.html), which is available before resource collection and can be invoked zero or more times.

for your second question, first checkout [`berkshelf`](https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf) -- a cookbook manager.
i would suggest forking a project only if the project is dead, otherwise i would consider to contribute to already implemented project so everybody will benefit from it; and you can always write your own [wrapper cookbook](https://www.chef.io/blog/2013/12/03/doing-wrapper-cookbooks-right/), you can also refer to [Chef wrapper cookbook best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466623/chef-wrapper-cookbook-best-practices).